# extend style material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

is there way to extend style on reactjs 
 I tried extend style but its dosent work

```
cellItem:{
 color: "black",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      fontSize: "0.8em"
    },
},

tableCellItem: {
   extend:"cellItem", --> here I extend parent style
    fontSize: "1.5em"
  },
  tableCellItemInSingleScreen: {
      extend:"cellItem",--> here I extend parent style
    fontSize: "2.5em"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use JavaScript features for this:

```
const styles = theme => {
  const cellItem = {
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("xs")]: {
      fontSize: "0.8em"
    }
  };
  return {
    cellItem,
    tableCellItem: {
      ...cellItem,
      fontSize: "1.5em"
    },
    tableCellItemInSingleScreen: {
      ...cellItem,
      fontSize: "2.5em"
    }
  };
};
```

There is an [extend plugin](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-extend?v=v10.0.0-alpha.16) within JSS that would cause your syntax to work, but it is not one of the plugins [included within Material-UI by default](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/advanced/#jss-plugins), but you can add that plugin.

Related answer: [Advanced styling in material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019444/advanced-styling-in-material-ui/58019642#58019642)