# Advanced styling in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I start to study material-ui and create a simple app in the SandBox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-ride-cmkrc

The style of jss is unusual for me, but if you help me with these two simple exercises, then I will understand everything.

First: I want union common properties of `ButtonLeft` and `ButtonRight` into new class and extend it: (https://github.com/cssinjs/jss-extend#use-rule-name-from-the-current-styles-object)

```
ButtonControll: {
    display: "none",
    position: "absolute",
    fontSize: "24px"
},
ButtonLeft: {
    extend: 'ButtonControll',
    left: "0",
},
ButtonRight: {
    extend: 'ButtonControll',
    right: "0",
}
```

But it's doesn't work =(

Second: I want the arrows to appear when you hover over the container, so I wrote this:

```
"&:hover .MuiIconButton-root": {
    display: "block"
}
```

Problem: `MuiIconButton-root` it is base className for all IconButtons? but I want something like this:

```
"&:hover ButtonLeft": {
    display: "block",
    backgroundColor: 'red' 
},
"&:hover ButtonRight": {
    display: "block",
    fontSize: '50px' 
}
```

Please, help me with these two simple tasks and then I will understand everything =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jss-plugin-extend` is not included by default in Material-UI.

You can find the list of included JSS plugins here: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#jss-plugins.

You can follow the instructions for adding additional plugins, but you can also achieve the same effect in other ways.

You can put the common properties in an object:

```
const commonButton = {
  display: "none",
  position: "absolute",
  fontSize: "24px"
};
export default props => ({
  ButtonLeft: {
    ...commonButton,
    left: "0",
  },
  ButtonRight: {
    ...commonButton,
    right: "0",
  }
});
```

Or since you have a `root` rule that the buttons are structurally within, you could apply all the common styles via nested rules in `root`:

```
export default props => ({
  root: {
    width: "250px",
    height: "182px",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    border: "1px solid black",
    position: "relative",
    "& $ButtonLeft, & $ButtonRight": {
      display: "none",
      position: "absolute",
      fontSize: "24px"
    },
    "&:hover $ButtonLeft, &:hover $ButtonRight": {
      display: "block"
    }
  },
  ButtonLeft: { left: "0" },
  ButtonRight: { right: "0" }
});
```

[image: Edit jss-nested]

The example above leverages [`jss-plugin-nested`](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.25) which **is** included in Material-UI by default. This also shows the appropriate syntax for the `hover` references.

Related answers:

- [Using material ui createStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871809/using-material-ui-createstyles/57873871#57873871)
- [how to use css in JS for nested hover styles, Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716926/how-to-use-css-in-js-for-nested-hover-styles-material-ui/57729101#57729101)

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question - what symbol '$' mean? I couldn't find any info about $ in css/jss

Comment: It is described in the `jss-plugin-nested` documentation that I linked to in the answer. https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.25#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet